# Defining 'app.config' for a WCF service using WebHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, webhttpbinding

I've got a WCF service that allows the uploading of files without using a MessageContract.

```
[OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadFile?filename={filename}")]
bool UploadFile(string filename, Stream fileContents);
```

I'm allowed to use another parameter beside the Stream object because it's part of the UriTemplate. Since the service runs as a Managed Windows Service, I have to start the ServiceHost manually.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    FileServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(FileService), new Uri("http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/FileService"));
    FileServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFile), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    FileServiceHost.Open();
}
```

With all of this, the service starts up and works just fine. However I wanted to move some of the above to the app.config file. To do this, I commented out the second line of `OnStart` and replaced the first line with `FileServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(FileService))`. Then I added that info to the app.config...

```
<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="Test.Server.FileService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/FileService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IFile"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And suddenly the service can no longer start up. It throws this exception on `FileServiceHost.Open` of the `OnStart` method: "For request in operation UploadFile to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream."

There must be something wrong with the way I'm defining the service in app.config, because when I remove it from there, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I fixed the issue by adding `webHttpBinding` to the endpoint behavior.

Added `behaviorConfiguration="TestBehavior"` to `<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IFile"/>`, and then defined `TestBehavior` as follows:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 1):

For streaming to be enabled in WCF, there are multiple restrictions. One of them is to have a single parameter of type `Stream` ([or any of two other types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx).)

This possibly means that WCF "guessed" that you were trying to stream content in your contract 
and defaulted the `TransferMode` to `Streamed` (This is purely a *guess*. It's not what is documented. Documentation says `TransferMode` defaults to `Buffered`.)

One option would be to set the transfer mode to `Buffered` explicitly in XML:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyWebBinding" transferMode="Buffered"/>
</webHttpBinding>
```

However, using the `Buffered` transfer mode, the content of the message would be entirely buffered before being sent, which is not a good thing with large files.

Another option would be to use the `Streamed` transfer mode. If you want to stream a file's content and provide a file name at the same time, you will have to define a custom `Message` class and send the file's metadata in the message headers:

```
[MessageContract]
public class UploadFileMessage
{
   [MessageHeader]
   public string Filename { get; set; }

   [MessageBodyMember]
   public Stream Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can't use MessageContracts as SOAP isn't supported for HTTP. Either way, it seems that using `WebHttpBehavior` on the endpoint fixes the problem.

Comment: Good to know. You might want to post and accept your own answer to your question then.